# What is the exact meaning of "fusion" in the terminology “fusion category”？

Tags: fusion-categories

I want to translate  the  terminology “fusion category” into Chinese, so I should know the exact meaning of "fusion". There are two translations in Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary:

1.the process or result of joining two or more things together to form one

2.(also nuclear fusion )( physics )the act or process of combining the nuclei(= central parts) of atoms to form a heavier nucleus, with energy being released

Which one? Or something else?

Maybe, the first one is a better choice. Who can tell me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: the first, this is definitely not physics.

Comment: I'll add that the second one is just a special case of the first one (where the things being joined are the nuclei of the atoms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that

$$
\text{"the process or result of joining two or more things together to form one"}
$$

Is a good description, that also reflects the origin of the terminology in the term "fusion category". Here, the things that are being joined (=fused) are the objects of the category, and the new entity that they form after fusion is their product (also called tensor product, or fusion product) in the category.

Comment: "Fusion" was used in group theory before fusion categories came about, in contexts as that of Burnside's fusion theorem and fusion systems, which show up in CFG theory. I always thought that fusion categories are so called because they ressemble/remind us of fusion systems.

Comment: Thank all of you! I will use "融合范畴" as the translation of "fusion category". It adopts the first meaning.

Comment: @Mariano: That doesn't make any sense to me.  As far as I can tell, the term fusion comes from conformal field theory; I really don't think they were thinking about representations in characteristic p.

Comment: @Mariano: I've always thought the name comes from representation theory and  quantum mechanics. Physicists sometimes call tensor product "fusion product", and talk about "fusion rules" for irreps.

Comment: Burnside's fusion theorem dates back to the late 19th/early 20th century. Then came Alperin's fusion theorem, and many descendants, starting in the mid 60s. Both of these concern how conjugacy of elements and subgroups of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a larger ambient groups come about ( within so called $p$-local subgroups, in steps). The development of fusion systems, using categories whose objects are subgroups of a fixed $p$-group, and whose morphisms are modelled on conjugation, came about rather later. I am not sure myself of the realtionship of these, if any, to fusion categories.

Comment: I agree with Ben. Namely, I'm completely certain that the term "fusion" in "fusion category" and in "fusion system" are unrelated. The first one comes from conformal field theory: in CFT one talks of field insertions at certain points on a Riemann surface (translate: field = object of a category) and one is interested at what happens when two points are made to collide. The mathematics that governs those kinds of things is actually that of *braided* fusion categories (more specifically, modular tensor categories), but the notion of fusion category --without a braiding-- is closely related.